# which jar contains IsoOutputStream and IsoBufferWrapperImpl class

Tags: java, mp4

I was running a [sample java program](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/source/browse/trunk/isoparser/src/test/java/com/coremedia/iso/boxes/SampleToChunkBoxTest.java?r=191) from google code of mp4parser.

I have included the respective jar file  isoviewer-2.0-RC-15.jar   from [mp4parser site](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/downloads/list)

Do I need to add any other jar??

but I am getting error  at line 32 and 34 for the class IsoOutputStream and IsoBufferWrapperImpl

How and which library to include for these two classes.

Here is program-

```
package com.coremedia.iso.boxes;

import com.coremedia.iso.IsoBufferWrapperImpl;
import com.coremedia.iso.IsoOutputStream;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: sannies
 * Date: 24.02.11
 * Time: 12:41
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class SampleToChunkBoxTest extends TestCase {


    public void testParse() throws Exception {
        SampleToChunkBox stsc = new SampleToChunkBox();
        List<SampleToChunkBox.Entry> l = new LinkedList<SampleToChunkBox.Entry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            SampleToChunkBox.Entry e = new SampleToChunkBox.Entry(i, 1, i * i);
            l.add(e);
        }
        stsc.setEntries(l);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stsc.getBox(new IsoOutputStream(baos));
        byte[] content = baos.toByteArray();

        SampleToChunkBox stsc2 = new SampleToChunkBox();
        stsc2.parse(new IsoBufferWrapperImpl(ByteBuffer.wrap(content, 8, content.length - 8)), content.length + 8, null, null);
        Assert.assertEquals(content.length, stsc2.getSize());


    }
}
```

Your reply will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "but I am getting error..." What is the exact error? Post the exact error message.

Comment: Hi Jesper,
I mentioned two classes IsoOutputStream and IsoBufferWrapperImpl and dont find any definition for that
So missing defintion for that
So I have asked for the library for them

Comment: So what is the error? `NoClassDefFoundError` or something else?

Comment: Yes,
See the Answer by GPS below.
He told correctly for IsoOutputStream class
Now I am still looking for IsoBufferWrapperImpl Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check  [this link](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/source/browse/trunk/isoparser/src/main/java/com/coremedia/iso/IsoOutputStream.java?r=2) out. They do have their own IsoOutputStream class.

You can get one jar from [Here](http://mavenhub.com/c/com/coremedia/iso/IsoOutputStream/jar)

Check out [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.mp4parser/isoparser/1.0-beta-6/com/coremedia/iso/IsoBufferWrapperImpl.java)  too.

Comment: Thanks GPS
can you please tell me how to add this java program in my program?
So that I can get the definition for mentioned two classes.

Comment: Also 
what about the IsoBufferWrapperImpl  class?
I didn't find any java file in iso folder for this class.

Comment: @rajivshah Check my update in answer.

Comment: Hi GPS
you are genius.
If possible then give me jar for 2nd link also.
anyways thanks much